# Turning a delimited string retrieved via AJAX back into a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, ajax

I imagine at some point my familiarity with PHP is making me write something incorrectly, but I've been reading up and can't seem to find a way to achieve what the below is intended to achieve. In the end, I should have a multidimensional array like such:

```
cardArray[#]
     'uniqueID' => "#";
     'cardName' => "blahblah";
     'series' => "blahblah";
```

(Where the #s are actual numbers, of course.) The string that is returned via AJAX is formatted such that each set of 3 is delimited by a colon and within each set each item is delimited by a pipe. (The final line I just threw in as a test to see if ANYTHING was getting stored.)

Here's the code:

```
function buildCardList() {
    var returnedString;
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            returnedString = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST","test02.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    var cardArray = new Array();

    cardArray = returnedString.split(":");

    for (var i = 0; i < cardArray.length; i++) {
        var tempVar = cardArray[i];
        var tempArr = tempVar.split("|");
        cardArray[i] = {
            "uniqueID" : tempArr[0],
            "cardName" : tempArr[1],
            "series" : tempArr[2]
        };
    }

    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = cardArray[0]['uniqueID'] + "<br>" + cardArray[0]['cardName'] + "<br>" + cardArray[0]['series'] + "<br><br>";
}
```

Comment: why not just use `json_encode()` in PHP, and `JSON.parse()` in javascript on the client?  This would relieve the need for all this mucking about with parsing...

Comment: also, all of your code (`var card Array = ...` through the `document.getElementById(...` should be inside of `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` function...

Comment: cgedefault, thank you for the recommendation. I'll give that a try tomorrow and get back to you with the results! (I searched using every relevant Google string I could think of and wasn't able to find the answer you just gave me, so thank you!)

Comment: RobG, it's nothing special, the PHP script just gets some info from the database and builds an associative array out of it.

Comment: @somecbusnerd—cool, I can work out the format from your code, it seems it's the HTTP request part that is broken. See cegfault's comment and remember what the A in AJAX stands for. The for loop is running before the response has returned and a value has been assigned to *returnedString*.